# [SQL]How to retrieve data within 2 days from certain period

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on retrieving data that has to meet to conditions without having an actual dataset -

- #Condition 1: Watched demo in 2021
- #Condition 2: After watching the demo, placed an order within 2 days

**Table name: visitor**

1. VISITOR_ID → unique ID representing a visitor
2. VISIT_ID → unique ID representing a visit
3. VISIT_DATETIME → timestamp representing when the visit happened
4. DEMO_VIDEO_WATCHES → yes/no flag representing whether the visitor watched the demo video

**Table name: ORDERS**

1. ORDER_ID → unique ID representing an eCommerce order
2. VISITOR_ID → unique ID representing the Google Analytics visitor
3. ORDER_DATETIME → timestamp representing when the order happened
4. ORDER_ARR → ARR (annual recurring revenue) from the order placed

**The question I am trying to answer is** -
Amount of ARR associated with visitors who watched the demo video in the 2021 calendar year and then placed an order within 2 days of watching the demo video.

**My answer is** -

```
SELECT SUM (ORDER_ARR) AS Amount_of_ARR
FROM
(SELECT *
FROM ORDERS 
WHERE DEMO_VIDEO_WATCHES = yes AND year(VISIT_DATETIME)='2021') t
INNER JOIN visitor v
ON t.VISITOR_ID = v.VISITOR_ID
WHERE t.ORDER_DATETIME BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '2 DAYS'AND NOW()
```

However the system says it's invalid, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you want the t.ORDER_DATETIME FROM last 2 days from now?

try:

```
where t.ORDER_DATETIME >= dateadd(day, -2, getdate())
```

you can play with the dateadd(day, -2, parameter) to get the data from the 2 days from the parameter

Comment: Or maybe instead of the getdate() you can put a parameter of whatever you want with stored procedure cand it will give you the 2 days before that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your query contains several errors.  In the sub-select:

1. The column `demo_video_watches` as it's from the `visitors` table
   but the sub-select only references the `order` table.
2. As used *yes* would be a column and as such that column does not
   exist.
3. There is no `year` function in Postgres, use the [extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)
   function instead.

Even with those corrected the query does not give orders *watched the video in 2021 and placed an order within 2 days* . Instead it gives the orders *placed an order within the last 2 days and watched the demo video sometime in 2021*.

Keeping the structure as close to yours but correcting all the above gives:

```
select sum(o.order_arr) "Amount of Arr"
  from orders   o 
  join visitors v 
    on (    o.visitor_id  = v.visitor_id )
 where v.demo_video_watches = 'yes'
   and extract('year' from v.visit_datetime) = 2021  
   and o.order_datetime - v.visit_datetime <= interval '2 days';
```

But there is no need for the sub-select at all. You can just do:

```
select sum(o.order_arr) "Amount of Arr"
  from orders   o 
  join visitors v 
    on (    o.visitor_id  = v.visitor_id )
 where v.demo_video_watches = 'yes'
   and extract('year' from v.visit_datetime) = 2021  
   and o.order_datetime - v.visit_datetime <= interval '2 days';
```

Note: you may want to google *subtracting timestamps in Postgres*.

Answer (score -1):

You can use BETWEEN...AND with dates in the WHERE clause:

```
where t.ORDER_DATETIME BETWEEN VISIT_DATETIME AND VISIT_DATETIME + 2
```

Comment: Please add context around code-only answers